# How to assign a predefined value to a struct member on type definition?

Tags: c, struct, types, initialization, c99

This is a long shot, but maybe there will be some ideas. On a system I programming, I have defined structures to program processor registers. The registers are comprised of several fields of a few bits each, with potentially "reserved" bits in between. When writing to a register, the reserved bits must be written as zeros.

For example:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t power    : 3;
    uint32_t reserved : 24;
    uint32_t speed    : 5;
} ctrl_t;

void set_ctrl()
{
    ctrl_t r = {
        .power    = 1;
        .speed    = 22;
        .reserved = 0;
    }

    uint32_t *addr = 0x12345678;

    *addr = *((uint32_t *) &r);

    return;
}
```

I want to be able to set the `reserved` field to a default value (0 in this example), and to spare the need for an explicit assignment (which happens a lot in our system).

Note that if the instantiated object is static, then by default an uninitialized field will be 0. However, in the above example there is no guarantee, and also I need to set any arbitrary value.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. If your variable is not static, then you need to initialize it explicitly.

Comment: There is no guarantee about a specific layout of bitfields. If you need that, they are not a good idea. Use an `unit32_t` and shift/masking instead. And you cast invokes undefined behaviour; you must mot access an object of one type as a different type! Read about the effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule.

Comment: @Olaf - on a given implementation (our embedded dev environment), the behaviour should be well defined (as it happens to be). The fact that I used all-`uint32_t` struct ensures that the fields are right-aligned and the size of that structure is exactly 32-bit.

Comment: @Olaf - you are right, though in that the alignment is not guaranteed *if I mix member types*. Initially, I defined the fields in terms of enums, and although the enums were promoted to ints, the compiler did not pack them correctly, even when I added the `packed` modifier.

Comment: Just omit `.reserved = 0;` . Unmentioned fields get set to 0.

Comment: @ysap This does not mean fields are where you expect! And `enum`s are even worse. They **are* `int`, but they can be stored in smaller sizes..

Comment: @M.M My fault. I somehow thought about anonymous resp. unused bits.

Comment: Can someone please explain why the downvote, so I can fix it?

Comment: Note: using `uint32_t` in a bit-field is implementation defined (ID) behavior.  only qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int` are specified.  C11 §6.7.2.1 5

Answer (score 2):

Structure *type* definitions in C cannot express values for structure members.  There is no mechanism for it.  Structure *instance* definitions can do.

> I want to be able to set the reserved field to a default value (0 in
>   this example), and to spare the need for an explicit assignment (which
>   happens a lot in our system).
>
> Note that if the instantiated object is static, then by default an
>   uninitialized field will be 0. However, in the above example there is
>   no guarantee, and also I need to set any arbitrary value.

That the default value you want is 0 is fortuitous.  You seem to have a misunderstanding, though: you cannot partially initialize a C object.  If you provide an initializer in your declaration of a structure object, then any members not explicitly initialized get the same value that they would do if the object had static storage duration and no initializer.

Thus, you can do this:

```
void set_ctrl() {
    ctrl_t r = {
        .power    = 1,
        .speed    = 22,
        // not needed:
        // .reserved = 0
    };

    // ...
```

If you want an easy way to initialize the whole structure with a set of default values, some non-zero, then you could consider writing a macro for the initializer:

```
#define CTRL_INITIALIZER { .power = 1, .speed = 22 }

// ...

void set_other_ctrl() {
    ctrl_t r = CTRL_INITIALIZER;
    // ...
```

Similarly, you can define a macro for partial content of an initializer:

```
#define CTRL_DEFAULTS .power = 1 /* no .speed = 22 */

// ...

void set_other_ctrl() {
    ctrl_t r = { CTRL_DEFAULTS, .speed = 22 };
    // ...
```

In this case you can even override the defaults:

```
    ctrl_t r = { CTRL_DEFAULTS, .power = 2, .speed = 22 };
```

... but it is important to remember to use only *designated* member initializers, as above, not undesignated values.

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd part of your answer (uninitialized member of a partially inited object is set to 0) is indeed new to me. However, this is only partially solving my problem (in the example, good only for reserved bits). As I mentioned, I want to set an arbitrary value.

Comment: I'm not following, @ysap.  Do you mean that you want a default initializer for the whole structure, that initializes some members to non-zero values?

Comment: I want a default initializer for *some* members, but I do not care to default-init the others, as this can be overriden by explicit run-time initialization.

Comment: Very well, @ysap, I think my updated answer covers what you want, or at least as much of that as C can do.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You initializer funtion is not practical when you have hundreds of registers. The macro-based one may be a place to look at.

Comment: @ysap Over-riding the default may incur a warning like "warning: initialized field overwritten [-Woverride-init]".  Use compiler option control to silence that warning as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done.

Values don't have "constructors" in the C++ sense in C. There's no way to guarantee that arbitrary code is run whenever a value of a certain type is created, so this can't be done. In fact "creation" of a value is quite a lose concept in C.

Consider this:

```
char buf[sizeof (ctrl_t)];
ctrl_t * const my_ctrl = (ctrl_t *) buf;
```

In this code, the pointer assignment would have to also include code to set bits of `buf` to various defaults, in order for it to work like you want.

In C, "what you see is what you get" often holds and the generated code is typically quite predictable, or better due to optimizations. But that kind of "magic" side-effect is really not how C tends to work.

It is probably better to not expose the "raw" register, but instead abstract out the existance of reserved bits:

```
void set_ctrl(uint8_t power, uint8_t speed)
{
  const uint32_t reg = ((uint32_t) power << 29) | speed;
  *(uint32_t *) 0x12345678 = reg;
}
```

This explicitly computes `reg` in a way that sets the unused bits to 0. You might of course add asserts to make sure the 3- and 5-bit range limits are not exceeded.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I figured out it is probably impossible, which is why I said "long shot" in my question. I practice, we do use macros for accessing regs, masking the fields for their right sizes. Your suggestion for an interface function is impractical when you have *many* registers.